# run [python manage.py custom commands] AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Tags: django

I'm getting an error running python manager.py commands with Django 4.2.

My development environment is:

- Python 3.10.10
- Django 4.2

```
# python manage.py run_cmdb_worker
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/python/lib/python3.10/pkgutil.py", line 417, in get_importer
    importer = sys.path_importer_cache[path_item]
KeyError: PosixPath('/www/cloudadmin')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/www/cloudadmin/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/www/cloudadmin/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/.pyvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/opt/.pyvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/opt/.pyvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 275, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/opt/.pyvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 48, in load_command_class
    module = import_module("%s.management.commands.%s" % (app_name, name))
  File "/usr/local/python/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/www/cloudadmin/apps/cmdb/management/commands/run_cmdb_worker.py", line 2, in <module>
    from cmdb.scheduler import Scheduler
  File "/www/cloudadmin/apps/cmdb/scheduler.py", line 3, in <module>
    from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
  File "/opt/.pyvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/apscheduler/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import get_distribution, DistributionNotFound
  File "/opt/.pyvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3260, in <module>
    def _initialize_master_working_set():
  File "/opt/.pyvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3234, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/.pyvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3272, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/opt/.pyvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 572, in _build_master
    ws = cls()
  File "/opt/.pyvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 565, in __init__
    self.add_entry(entry)
  File "/opt/.pyvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 621, in add_entry
    for dist in find_distributions(entry, True):
  File "/opt/.pyvenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1988, in find_distributions
    importer = get_importer(path_item)
  File "/usr/local/python/lib/python3.10/pkgutil.py", line 421, in get_importer
    importer = path_hook(path_item)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1632, in path_hook_for_FileFinder
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1504, in __init__
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 182, in _path_isabs
AttributeError: 'PosixPath' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Do you have the same problem?

I had to modify the setting of BASE_DIR in the settings.py file for it to work.

```
# BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent 
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Comment: Are you sure you're running python 3.10? What is the output of `which python` ?

Comment: Or just `python --version`

Comment: # python --version
Python 3.10.10

Answer (score 0):

here're what i would check.

- in which path i am running this command.
- ensure the module i added or imported have `__init__.py` file.
- if i'm using virtual environment, ensure to activate it.
- did i change some directory name and then fotgot change virtualenv settings.

hope this helps!

Comment: first of all thank you.

1. I run the command in the Django root directory
2. I am using custom django-admin commands
3. I am using a Python virtual environment, make sure it has been activated
4. The virtualenv settings are correct